# How to access other files in any editor?

Tags: java, editor

For example I have Main.java and test.java. test has public static int bro = 5; so i try to print test.bro from Main but the class test is not found. An IDE like Eclipse takes care of this for me but how do I do this with an editor? Sorry noob question. I'm in cmd in the directory of deez files and i type javac Main.java, den java Main. Thanks.

file Main.java:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(test.bro);
   }
}
```

file test.java:

```
public class test {
   public static int bro = 5;
}
```

Comment: **Edit** the question and show us the source code for both classes, and the commands you execute to compile and run the code, including which Java version you're using. Said another way, show us a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So suppose you have two source files: `Main.java` and `test.java` then you need to compile them first.

You can do it via command `javac Main.java test.java`. That command will produce 2 files in your current directory: `Main.class` and `test.class`. Which contain compiled java code.

Now you need to run your main class with classpath which contains both of your classes. So you need to run command `java -cp . Main`. Where `.` represents directory with your compiled classes.

Comment: Thank you! Surely there must be some tool to do like if i had 7 files instead of two would i necessarily have to type javac 1.java 2.jaava 3 .java... etc.?

Comment: Last time I was trying to figure it out I came to conclusion that yes, you have to type each file. But I can be wrong.